# Symmetric product of projective space.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

> Let $\mathbb{P}_3 = (\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1)/S_3$ be $3$-symmetric product of Riemann sphere $\mathbb{P}^1$, show that $\mathbb{P}_3 \simeq \mathbb{P}^3$ is holomorphic isomorphism.

Can we define $g: \mathbb{P}_3\to \mathbb{P}^3$ as
$$
g: ([x_1:y_1],[x_2:y_2],[x_3:y_3]) \mapsto [x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2y_3:x_1y_2x_3+x_1y_2y_3+y_1x_2x_3+y_1x_2y_3:y_1y_2x_3+y_1y_2y_3:x_1x_2x_3:y_1y_2y_3]
$$
?
And how to prove it is a holomorphic isomorphism? Thanks.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry for my stupidity, I have edited my question.

Comment: Maybe you can use the fact that $\mathbb C\times \mathbb C\times \mathbb C/S^3\cong \mathbb C^3$ and use charts $\mathbb C\times \mathbb C\times \mathbb C$ is a to cover $\mathbb P^1\times \mathbb P^1\times \mathbb P^1$ and look at how different charts on the quotient are glued together.

Comment: What I had mind was to associate with a complex number $z$ a factor $(T-z)$ and to the point at infinity the factor $1$. I think this can be homogenized to read that to the point $[x:y]\in\Bbb{P}^1$ we associate the factor $yT-x$. Then we could try and first map a triple of points to the polynomial
$$g(T)=\prod_{i=1}^3(y_iT-x_i).$$
Then we associate the polynomial
$$g(T)=g_3T^3+g_2T^2+g_1+g_0$$
with the point $[g_0:g_1:g_2:g_3]$.
Because that product is stable under permutations, this should be a well-defined map. But I lack the tools to decide whether it gives a holomorphic isomorphism.

Comment: ^ a well-defined map from $(\Bbb{P}^1\times\Bbb{P}^1\times\Bbb{P}^1)/S_3$ to $\Bbb{P}^3$.

Comment: Your proposed map $g$ ends up in $\mathbb{P}^4$? (it has $5$ components)